# Array of pointers initialization

Tags: c, pointers

```
 char **arr;
 arr = (char **)calloc(1,sizeof(char*));

 for(i = 0; i< 16; i++)
    if(arr[i] = (char *)calloc(1, 2*sizeof(char)) == NULL)
        perror("Memory cannot be allocated to arr[i]", %d);
```

The above code throws an error inside the for loop, when i am trying to allocate memory to arr[i]. Is anything wrong with this allocation. Essentially, i want to  store  16 strings of length 2. I've tried it with array of pointers too (char *arr[16]). I have tried looking for resources on double pointer initializations using malloc() and calloc() and couldn't find many . If you could point out some links, that would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: The code is not compilable. It is normally recommened that you post the *real* code you were using.

Comment: @Andrey - I didn't use a %d in perror. I just printed the error string.

Comment: That's not everything yet. Your assignment to `arr[i]` under the `if` with comparison to `NULL` is missing braces, which makes it incorrectly associated. It cannot compile as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to allocate enough memory for 16 pointers, not just one.

```
arr = (char **)calloc(16, sizeof(char*));
```

What happens with your code is that `arr` has enough memory only for one pointer, so `arr[0] = <something>` is correct, but `arr[1]` and higher is touching memory that doesn't belong to the program.

Additionally, the way you assign the string pointers is wrong. You are assigning 0 or 1 values, depending on whether the result if `calloc` is `NULL`. You need to add parentheses there:

```
if ((arr[i] = (char *)calloc(1, 2*sizeof(char))) == NULL)
    perror("Memory cannot be allocated to arr[%d]", i);
```

Er even better:

```
for(i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    arr[i] = (char *)calloc(1, 2*sizeof(char));
    if (arr[i] == NULL) {
        perror("Memory cannot be allocated to arr[%d]", i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that not what i am doing inside the for loop? Am i missing something here.

Comment: No, you are allocating memory for one pointer, and then (incorrectly) overwriting memory that doesn't belong to your program.

Comment: No, you are allocating the individual strings in the array. You must first make sure you have room for 16 pointers to the strings. Try what Lukas suggested and you'll see it works.

Also remember you need to free each string + the entire array with 16 individual calls to free()

Comment: I tried the above code. The code compiles fine, but memory is not being allocated to arr[i], perror says memory cannot be allocated.

Comment: That's because the assignment is wrong, `a = b == c` is evaluated as `a = (b == c)`, not as `(a = b) == c`. You need to add parentheses there.

Comment: @Lukáš Lalinský: But that still won't compile. The result of '==' is an int, and the LHS in that assignment is a pointer. You can't assign an int to a pointer without a disgnostic message from the compiler.

Comment: @Lukáš Lalinský: Concerning your version of the code - it won't compile. `perror` is not `printf`. It doesn't do what you think it does. `perror` accepts only one parameter.

Answer (score 6):

When you use `calloc`, it is customary to use the first parameter to pass the number of elements in the array and the second parameter to pass the size of an element. So, to allocate an array of 16 pointers, one'd normally use `calloc(16, <pointer size>)`, not `calloc(1, 16 * <pointer size>)`, although both do the same thing. In your code you apparently completely forgot about 16 and allocated only 1 pointer.

Don't cast the result of 'calloc'.

Avoid using `sizeof(<type>)` when calculating size for memory allocation functions. Prefer to use `sizeof *<pointer>` instead.

If you want to store srings of length 2, you need a buffer of at least 3 characters long (an extra character for zero-terminator).

Memory allocation failure doesn't normally set `errno`, so `perror` is not an appropriate function to use here.

Yor assignment to `arr[i]` in `if` condition is missing braces. The operations are associated incorrectly. It won't compile as is.

```
char **arr; 
arr = calloc(16, sizeof *arr); 
for(i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    if((arr[i] = calloc(3, sizeof *arr[i]) == NULL)
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory cannot be allocated");
```

Finally, an unnamed "magic constant" (16 and 3) is most of the time not a good idea.

Comment: Don't cast the result of 'calloc'. Why?

Comment: Firstly, it is unnecessary. Secondly, it is fairly dangerous (see the FAQ c-faq.com/malloc/mallocnocast.html). Thirdly, type names are for delarations, they are not supposed to be mentioned in the "regular" code.

Comment: But again, the main point is that they are completely *unnecessary*, so the main question here is *why on Earth did you put a cast there*?

Comment: People used to C++ usually do that, because it would be an error, or at least a warning, without the cast.

Comment: @Lukáš Lalinský: In 99 cases out of 100 this has noting to do with C++. Usually this is the people who studied C by some archaic books (like the first edition of K&R) and source codes, which were written when C had no 'void *' and 'malloc' returned 'char *' (and the dinosaurs roamed the earth)

Comment: Well, I disagree about the 99 out of 100 cases. You can't implicitly cast `void*` in `char*` in C++. At least for me, this is the reason to cast it manually even in C.

Comment: Well, you must be that 1 out of 100 then :) I, for one, write mostly C++ code, but at the same time have no trouble avoiding excessive casts in C code.

Comment: There's a good reason other than custom to prefer `calloc(number, size)` over `calloc(1, number * size)` - in the former, `calloc` should check for the multiplication overflowing the size of `size_t` and wrapping, whereas in the latter you need to do it yourself.

Answer (score 3):

```
arr = (char **)calloc(1,sizeof(char*));
```

allocates one pointer to pointer to char.

> Essentially, i want to store 16 strings of length 2

```
char **arr = calloc(16, sizeof *arr);

if (!arr) exit(-1); /* bail out somehow */

for(i = 0; i < 16; i++)
  if((arr[i] = calloc(2, sizeof *arr[ i ])) == NULL)
    printf("Memory cannot be allocated to arr[ %d ]", i + 1);
```

Check the parenthesization as well in your `if` condition and `printf` statement. Does your code even compile?

Comment: yeah, my code compiles but throws a segmentation fault during runtime.

Comment: @Deepak Konidena: Please, don't invent things. The code you posted in the original question does not (and did not) not compile. Either you posted the wrong code, or something else happened, but the code in th OP, once again, is not compilable.

Comment: @dirkgently: You forgot `sizeof` in both cases. Also, `perror` doesn't do what you think it does. And why did 16 and 2 (3?) suddenly switch places?

Comment: @Andrey - yeah, you're right. I just printed the error string and did not use %d.

Comment: Still won't compile. See my comment to the original post.

Answer (score 1):

Storing two characters directly is less expensive than storing a pointer, so I'd suggest dropping one level of indirection and use a contigous block of memory:

```
char (*arr)[2] = calloc(16, sizeof *arr);
```

Also keep in mind that your character sequences can't be strings as you didn't provide memory for the terminating `0`.